# DDD PHP Doctrine2 - Mapping

Tags: php, doctrine, mapping, domain-driven-design

I would hear how do you peoploe map domain objects with data mapper pattern in doctrine2. I just went to a problem, when my aggregates use clean php array and use php functions to work with array array_shift for example. Anyway it was good till I started to integrate doctrine mappings with my domain entities. The problem was about how does doctrine works with assosciations between entities.  Whenever my aggregate root had one to many relationship (or any other tbh), doctrine used ArrayCollection class on that, instead of just an normal array. I could just use one of the methods like toArray(), but I would have to check first in domain object if it is an doctrine collections class, that would be dirty.  So anyway I chose to do it in my aggregate repository, before returning the class. I made reflection class set property to public and replaced it with clean php array. Works less dirty, but still I dont like it tbh.  So my question is, how do you guys handle limitations od doctrine or maybe for you there is no something like limitation :).  And next question, if you guys use Doctrine ArrayCollection in your domain classes?

Comment: Just cast to a regular array.  $items = (array)$entity->getItems();

Answer (score 2):

What are you using those array for?

I suspect that the problem is that you are using arrays instead of objects. Objects should reflect the domain and provide you with methods that exists in the domain. If you are replacing the real world behaviour with arrays you are not really following the DDD principles.

Simple example:

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="sales_flat_order")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Candle\OrderBundle\Repository\Mage\OrderRepository")
 */
class Order implements OrderInterface
{

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="OrderItem", mappedBy="order", cascade={"persist"})
     * 
     * @var OrderItem[]
     */
    private $orderItems;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->orderItems = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Check if all Items are marked as scanned 
     * 
     * @param integer $warehouseId Warehouse ID to check for. 
     * 
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isOrderScanCompleted($warehouseId)
    {
        foreach ($this->orderItems as $orderItem) {
            if ($orderItem->getWarehouseId() == $warehouseId
                && !$orderItem->isScanComplete()) {
                return FALSE;
            }
        }

        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

I could have iterated through array of DB values of related OrderItems and check values that constitute "isScanComplete" flag, but I decided to implement it and thus encapsulate it in OrderItem class. Hence no need for array of values.

Comment: Okey, but now you're coupled to doctrine with ArrayCollection. If you would use simple php array , you would be free of vendors. 
Now let's say, that you can retrieve orderItems from your Order Aggregate. You're free to go to use functions like ->add(), ->remove() on ArrayCollection class, so I dont see encapsulation here. Someone can use your api in wrong way.

Comment: In my current project I'm using few dependencies for my domain "mathiasverraes/money" value object and "doctrine/collections" - collection and I don't have any problem with that. 'Be free of vendors' is not point of Domain, with big domain you will need to use vendors, you can't write all by you self. What you need to care is isolation domain from application and infrastructure.

Comment: The problem with Doctrine collections and the ORM is that you cannot use custom `Collection` implementations since you will always receive a `PersistenCollection` in your proxies. We needed a lot of logic in our collections, so we went for an own collection implementation. But this decision should be based on actual use cases.

Answer (score 1):

In my projects I use doctrine entities (mapping information is moved to yml files and is outside of domain) for this purpose.

Doctrine documentation stated that:

> The Collection interface and ArrayCollection class, like everything else in the Doctrine namespace, are neither part of the ORM, nor the DBAL, it is a plain PHP class that has no outside dependencies apart from dependencies on PHP itself (and the SPL). Therefore using this class in your domain classes and elsewhere does not introduce a coupling to the persistence layer. The Collection class, like everything else in the Common namespace, is not part of the persistence layer. You could even copy that class over to your project if you want to remove Doctrine from your project and all your domain classes will work the same as before.

So it's fine to use DoctrineCollection within domain, just extend it to replace easily in case you will migrate to other framework/orm.

Also please see this slides [https://www.slideshare.net/*leopro*/clean-architecture-with-ddd-layering-in-php-35793127](https://www.slideshare.net/_leopro_/clean-architecture-with-ddd-layering-in-php-35793127)

Which refers to this example app https://github.com/leopro/trip-planner

You might want to use yml/xml files for your schema mapping information instead of annotations within entity to remove this dependency from domain as well.

This question was posted long ago, but this answer might be still useful for other users

Comment: The question is pretty old. I do have another kind of problems now :).

Still thanks for trying :)